# How to print int values with a slash and in ascending order?

Tags: python, list, division

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]
```

output = `[1/4,2/5,3/6]`

I need output should contain slash and ascending order.
I searched a lot not finding any solution to print the values with slash i.e `1/4,2/5,3/6`

Comment: Build a string using `str(numerator) + "/" + str(denominator)`

Answer (score 2):

```
a= [(f'{x}/{y}') for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]
output = ""
for i in range(0, len(l1)): output += str(l1[i]) + "/" + str(l2[i]) + ","

output = list(output[:-1].split(","))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip() to put them together and sorted() with a key parameter to get them in ascending order.  The res is merely formatting of the print call:

```
l1=[3,2,1]
l2=[6,5,4]

print(*(f"{n}/{d}" for n,d in sorted(zip(l1,l2),key=lambda nd:nd[0]/nd[1])),
      sep=",")

1/4,2/5,3/6
```

*BTW, if you want to make sure that your solution actually sorts the values, you should use an example that is not already sorted*